# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "en un periquete"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, españa

Acabo de toparme con la expresión "en un periquete", recogida en la RAE tal que así:

> **[periquete](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Se6SxOM)**
>
> 1. m. coloq. Brevísimo espacio de tiempo. *Volverá en un periquete.*

Es una expresión que me resulta divertida, pero ahora me estaba preguntando ¿de dónde viene? ¿Alguien conoce la etimología de la palabra? Buscando un poco he podido encontrar [algunas alternativas](http://rociodiazgomez.blogspot.com.es/2012/07/en-un-periquete-origen-de-la-expresion.html):

- Corominas la da como derivado de "perico", originariamente diminutivo de "Pero" (Pedro) y a partir de ahí "especie de papagayo" (periquito) y, por otra vía, "antiguo tocado de pelo postizo".
- Podría ser una metátesis de "repiquete", voz que el Diccionario define como "repique vivo y rápido de campanas parecido al redoble del tambor". Lógicamente, el repiquete (que, según el Diccionario de Autoridades se producía golpeando la campana con un instrumento de hierro distinto del badajo) debía de ser de breve duración (pensemos en el repiqueteo de la campanilla en la misa católica), y por ahí se formaría la expresión.
- Viene del griego clásico *peri*, que significa "alrededor de", "en torno a", etc. y *kete*, que viene de *keteo* o *keteomai*, en voz pasiva; en ambos casos significa "buscar bajo los velos lo que nadie ve".
- Vendría del prefijo *peri* (entorno alrededor) y de la raíz *keté* o *cuete* (embriaguez). Vendría a significar algo así como "andar ebrio alrededor de algo".

La verdad es que la que más me convence es la de la metátesis de "repiquete", pero me falla porque en el CORDE aparecen concordancias con la expresión "en un periquete" desde 1871, pero ninguna de "en un repiquete". Y en la hemeroteca del BNE encuentro el siguiente [texto de 1806](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0003723751&page=5&search=periquetes&lang=es):

> ¿Pues qué no tiene esta buena señora hombres sapientísimos, de autoridad, de peso y poder, para los que sería un juego tales combates, y los quales en dos periquetes la sacarían triunfante, lucidísima y completamente vengada?

¿Qué opináis vosotros? ¿Alguna otra opción?

Comment: No se usa ni se entiende por hispanoamérica. Por eso le coloco la etiqueta España.

Comment: @DGaleano gracias por la aclaración, la verdad es que ignoraba si era usada fuera de España. Con la etiqueta quedará más claro el ámbito de uso.

Comment: Hispanoamèrica es muy grande, soy de Uruguay y esta expresión la conozco muy bien.

Comment: En Argentina se entiende, aunque probablemente sólo la usen personas de más de 60 años a esta altura.

Answer (score 3):

Propongo una teoría que he ideado tras investigar un poco. [Antonio Alcalá Venceslada](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonio_Alcal%C3%A1_Venceslada) fue un escritor, poeta, archivero, filósofo y profesor español, nacido en Marmolejo, provincia de Jaén (España). En 1933 publicó su *Vocabulario Andaluz*, obra reconocida y premiada por la RAE.

Precisamente en los archivos de la RAE, en el [fichero general](http://web.frl.es/fichero.html) existe [una ficha (PDF)](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_P/LETRA_P_PDF/PERIQUETE/00001215.pdf) sobre la palabra "periquete", extraída de la citada obra, que dice lo siguiente:

> **Periquete.** m. Castañuela frotando fuertemente los dedos cordial y pulgar. (Prov. de Jaén.)

Y pone como ejemplo:

> *"...comenzó a hacer sonoros **periquetes** con los dedos marcando el compás del dos por uno..."*

Esta cita es de un artículo de Alfredo Cazabán Laguna, un escritor y periodista jiennense. Por tanto, tenemos que en Jaén se conocía como "periquete" al chasquear los dedos, acción que produce un sonido que, como sabemos, dura un periquete.

El problema que tengo con esta teoría es que ignoro desde cuándo se conoce como "periquete" a este gesto en Jaén. Por tanto, existe la posibilidad de que la expresión "en un periquete" sea de origen andaluz, suponiendo que el mencionado "periquete" sea más antiguo; pero también puede ser que primero viniese la expresión "en un periquete" y luego se le diera al gesto el nombre de "periquete" dada la brevedad del mismo.

Comment: En el NTLLE figura en el diccionario de Gaspar y Roig de 1855: "PERIQUETE: voz que solo se usa en las fr. IR, VENIR O HACER ALGUNA COSA EN UN PERIQUETE y equivale a verificarlo en un instante, en muy corto tiempo.

Comment: _[El folk-lore andaluz: órgano de la sociedad de ese nombre](https://archive.org/stream/elfolkloreandal00andagoog#page/n158/mode/2up/search/periquete)_ señala que "en un dos por tres" y "en un periquete" son "dos modismos andaluces análogos". Lamentablemente, no aventura el origen de "en un periquete", pero sí dice que es andaluz.

Comment: Me convence lo del gesto de los dedos pues tb se usa para indicar velocidad